# Can't install android device driver

Tags: android, usb-drive

I am trying to connect my Motorola device to Android Studio. When I connect device to my computer it shows **"Driver not found"**, then I download the driver tried to install it from **"Device manager"**. All the time I trying to browse the folder it shows a message.

[image]

Anybody can help me from this?. Thank you...

Comment: better to used `Pdanet+` in android

Comment: http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/ the driver supply with the sdk. just go thru this tutorial.

Comment: @Maor Hadad, Thank you very much... :)

Answer (score 2):

adb is responsible for communication b/w device to system

you should give a try to adb driver installer which 
you can get at given link

this is universal adb driver

http://adbdriver.com/upload/AdbDriverInstaller.exe

Comment: After hours trying, this seems to have solved my issue. Thanks, Raj!

Comment: unfortunately the link is dead

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it would require [getting the Google USB Driver](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) from the SDK Manager and then [installing it for your device](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#InstallingDriver).

Answer (score 0):

go to http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html and download the oem usb driver and install it and follow these mention steps
http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html#Win7

Comment: whats the model no of your Motorola device and your windows version ,because in windows 10 some device are not able to connect with adb

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to install [User-Mode Driver Framework version 1.11 update for Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38421)?

Worked for me after install it.

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you install driver from hardware vender's web site.

For example
your device is motorola then please install driver from motorola and try gain.
http://www.motorola.com/getmdmwin

or use linux os to avoid driver issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my tool, it install device specific drivers, you just have to

1. connect the phone in USB Debugging mode to PC and run the tool.

Here is the link to the [repo](https://github.com/fawazahmed0/Latest-adb-fastboot-installer-for-windows)